# не срабатывает самописный автономный валидатор Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, валидация

**Задача:** необходимо сделать валидацию строки на отсутствие в ней цифр.

**Попытка решения:**
в корневой  папке создал папку *myValidators* c файлом *strWithoutNumberValidator* следующего содержания:

```
namespace app\myValidators;

use yii\validators\Validator;

class strWithoutNumberValidator extends Validator
{
  public function validateAttribute($model,$attribute)
  {

    if(preg_match('~[0-9]+~',$attribute))
    {
        $this->addError($model,$attribute,'Name must include letters 
                                                                only!');

    }
  }
 }
```

в файле модели:
      namespace app\models;

```
  use Yii;

  class OrderModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
  {

    public static function tableName()
    {
       return 'order';
    }


    public function rules()
    {
       return [

        [['name'],\app\myValidators\strWithoutNumberValidator::class],

        ['email',\yii\validators\EmailValidator::class],
        ['phone', \yii\validators\StringValidator::class, 'length' => 
                                                              [10,10]],
        ['phone',\yii\validators\NumberValidator::class]
       ];
    }
 }
```

но вопреки ожиданиям серверная валидация не срабатывает!
Не могу понять где ошибка...

Answer (score 1):

А всё дело в том, что вместо $attribute ничего не передается!нужно использовать $model->$attribute в validateAtrribute!